# Java 8 streams and lambdas

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have very interesting part of code that I want to refactor to use java 8 streaming API capabilities

```
Map<String, Object> user = ...// pull user from somewhere
List<Map<String, Object>> attributes = ...// pull attributes from somewhere
List<Map<String, Object>> processedAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map<String, Object> attribute : attributes) {
        if (!((List<Map<String, Object>>) attribute.get("subAttributes")).isEmpty()) {
            for (Map<String, Object> subAttribute : (List<Map<String, Object>>) attribute.get("subAttributes")) {
                if (!user.containsKey(subAttribute.get("name"))
                        && Boolean.TRUE.equals(subAttribute.get("required"))) {
                    processedAttributes.add(subAttribute);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How can this be refactored using java 8 streams?

Comment: Replace `for (iterable)` with `iterable.forEach(x -> statement)`, and if's with `iterable.filter(x -> condition)`. Looking at that loop, the statement will be quite long.

Comment: you can also use `map` and `filter(List::isEmpty)`.

Comment: Interesting question. Do you think you could read up a bit on the `Stream` API and come up with a solution? We can help you if you get stuck somewhere? Or is this a coding request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be rewritten in pretty straightforward way using the `flatMap`:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> processedAttributes = attributes.stream()
        .flatMap(
                attribute -> ((List<Map<String, Object>>) attribute
                        .get("subAttributes")).stream())
        .filter(subAttr -> !user.containsKey(subAttr.get("name"))
                && Boolean.TRUE.equals(subAttr.get("required")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that `isEmpty` check is unnecessary in your code: if the `List` is empty, then `for` loop will not be executed anyways.